# Como remover partes do name de um field em uma estrutura serializada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialização

Estou serializando meu form para depois convertê-lo em JSON, e eu preciso remover a string "`PessoaViewModel.`" de todos os fields. Os dados serializados ficam assim:

```
"PessoaViewModel.Id=2&PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza=Juridica&PessoaViewModel.PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoaId=2&"
```

Em vez de ficar `"PessoaViewModel.Id=2"`, deverá ficar "`Id=2`".

```
var pessoaViewModel = $("form :input")
.filter(function (index, element) {
    return $(element).val() != '';
})
.serialize();
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei como de onde está vindo esse `PessoaViewModel.`, mas você pode removê-lo com um `replace` usando uma expressão regular. Basta acrescentar `.replace(/PessoaViewModel\./g, '')` no serialize:

```
var pessoaViewModel = $("form :input")
.filter(function (index, element) {
    return $(element).val() != '';
})
.serialize()
.replace(/PessoaViewModel\./g, '');
```

Note que é preciso escapar o ponto com `\.`, pois o ponto tem uma função própria na expressão regular.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado :)